# Logging using the data from database of C# webservices

Tags: c#

I want to get records from database against Email and Password, I have searched and wasting lot of time but I didn't get anything.

```
[WebMethod]
public bool CheckLogin(string Email, string Password)
{
   return getEmail(Email, Password);
}

public bool getEmail(String Email, String Password)
{
        SqlConnection NewCon;
        NewCon = Class1.GetConnection();
        NewCon.Open();
        bool check = false;
        string pa;

        SqlCommand CheckCmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * from RegisterUsers WHERE Email ='" + Email + "' and Password='" + Password + "'", NewCon);
        CheckCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        CheckCmd.Parameters.Add("@Email", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Email;

        SqlDataReader sdr = CheckCmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (sdr.Read())
        {
            pa = sdr.GetString(8); // for Password column

            if (pa == Password)
            {
                check = true;
            }
            break;
        }

        NewCon.Close();
        return check;
    }
```

Comment: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
 c:\Users\MuhammadAli\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\WebSer\WebSer\WebService1.asmx.cs:line 162
   at WebSer.WebService1.CheckLogin(String Email, String Password) in c:\Users\MuhammadAli\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\WebSer\WebSer\WebService1.asmx.cs:line 137

Comment: i received this error when i run my webservices

Comment: **READ UP** on **SQL injection** attacks and stop concatenating together your SQL statements **right now** - use **parametrized queries** instead!

Comment: Sir actually i am new to the web services, will you please tell me more clearly

Comment: SqlCommand CheckCmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * from RegisterUsers WHERE Email ='" + Email + "'", NewCon); you mean to say this case

Comment: See: http://software-security.sans.org/developer-how-to/fix-sql-injection-microsoft-.net-with-parameterized-queries

Comment: Sir i didn't get any idea from that link.

Comment: My scenario is that i want to get record from database against sql query.Actually we are making and android application and Web Application, when a user login via Android application the Query pass via web services and get details from SQL Server Database